# Set variable to any when there is no value set to variable

Tags: php, pdo

This is the function to search value `refone` and paginate:

```
public function get_all($refone,$per_page,$page_offset) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ". self::$table_name . " WHERE rq_detail LIKE :refone";
        $query .= " ORDER BY rq_created DESC";
        $query .= " LIMIT $per_page";
        $query .= " OFFSET $page_offset";
        $sth = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        if(empty($refone)){
            $refone = '';
        } else {
            $refone = "%".$refone."%";
        }
        
        $sth->bindParam('refone', $refone);
        $sth->execute();
        return $row = $sth -> fetchAll();
    }
```

Now the idea is on `refone` if there is no value provide to mentioned variable the result will show an error of:

```
Notice: Undefined index: refone in C:\wamp\www\dms\view\req\index.php on line 25
```

Here if you see the function in case not empty it will show like value from start and end but in case of empty I have tried but now worked for me.

NOTE: in case of blank it should result any like what ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error on this line:

```
$sth->bindParam('refone', $refone);
```

should be

```
$sth->bindParam(':refone', $refone);
```

with `:`

Also, I would put the WHERE clause inside your conditional:

```
public function get_all($refone,$per_page,$page_offset) {

    if(!empty($refone)){
        $refone_condition = ' WHERE rq_detail LIKE :refone ';
        $refone = "%".$refone."%";
    } else {
        $refone_condition = ' ';
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ". self::$table_name . $refone_condition;
    $query .= " ORDER BY rq_created DESC";
    $query .= " LIMIT " . intval($per_page);
    $query .= " OFFSET " . intval($page_offset);
    $sth = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    if(!empty($refone)){
      $sth->bindParam(':refone', $refone);
    }

    $sth->execute();
    return $row = $sth -> fetchAll();
}
```

Notice that I also sanitized $per_page and $page_offset with intval().  You can also bind them like you did with :refone so the prepared statement would take care of sanitizing them.

The same with more generic code:

```
public function get_all($refone = NULL, $per_page = NULL, $page_offset = NULL) {

    $args = array();
    $conditions = array();
    $offset_limit_clause = '';

    if(!is_null($refone)){
        $conditions[] = ' rq_detail LIKE ? ';
        $args[] = "%".$refone."%";
    }

    if(!is_null($page_offset)){
        $offset_limit_clause = ' OFFSET ? ';
        $args[] = intval(($page_offset-1) * $per_page); // offset is expressed in pages
                                                      // must convert to records
        if(empty($per_page)) $per_page = 30; // $per_page cannot be 0 if $page_offset > 1
    }

    if(!is_null($per_page)){
        $offset_limit_clause .= ' LIMIT ? ';
        $args[] = $per_page;
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . self::$table_name . 
    (count($conditions)?" WHERE ":"") . implode(" AND ", $conditions) .
    " ORDER BY rq_created DESC " . $offset_limit_clause;

    $sth = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    $sth->execute($args);
    return $row = $sth -> fetchAll();
}
```

Last but not least, you can set defaults for the parameters in a function:

```
public function get_all($refone = NULL, $per_page = 30, $page_offset = 0) {
```

If you dont pass anything the defaults will be used, but if you pass NULL or empty/falsy values like 0 or "", those will be received, so I don't think this is what you are looking for here.

Comment: thank you, what is the benefit of intval() ?? do i need to use both bindparam and intval or one is ok

Comment: It prevents the visitor to enter values that are not integers, like valid -but malicious- SQL code that would be executed, stealing or erasing your data.

Comment: No, you don't need to do both.  Binding the parameters forces MySQL to interpret them as expected, in this case as integers.  You could use intval() for integers an mysql_real_escape_string() for strings, but the right thing to do is to bind them.  Binding the parameters is the main benefit of using PDO (which is what you are using here).

Comment: Sorry for the buggy code, I keep editing it.  Be sure to try the last version.  :)

Comment: Thanks you, i will use this new version, by the way is it possible i echo the total row searched in this function or i need new one.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot this . Correct/add this...

```
$refone = '$';
```

Comment: in this case the value for ($refone) will be ($) which is not on the value for the refone column of table and will result noting.

Comment: did same resutl, when i dont pass any value for $refone

Comment: Okay, so let me do s test and then I get back to you.

Comment: Okay, pass noting to the variable $refone, the function have to assign it self. and result every thing on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public function get_all($refone,$per_page,$page_offset) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ". self::$table_name . " WHERE rq_detail LIKE :refone";
    $query .= " ORDER BY rq_created DESC";
    $query .= " LIMIT $per_page";
    $query .= " OFFSET $page_offset";
    $sth = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    if(empty($refone)){
        $refone = '';
    } else {
        $refone = "%".$refone."%";
    }

    $sth->bindParam(':refone', $refone);
    $sth->execute();
    return $row = $sth -> fetchAll();
}
```